# Cannot update CoreData Model after getting a Fetch Request

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchrequest

My app is set up like this, I have two view controllers coming off of my RootViewController - a simple main selection page with two buttons. The top button sends me to ViewController 1 where I take a photo and insert data in 6 text fields about the photo. I then hit a save button which saves those entities to my ManagedObjectModel TargetData inside my ManagedObjectContext. The second button on the main page leads to a TableVIewController where I have called an NSFetchedResults sorta thing to update the TableView.

It works pretty well...at least until I run the TableViewController once. I can add as many photos with text data as I want until I show the TableViewController, at which point, upon leaving the page, the TableViewController will only show the objects it loaded the first time I opened the page, not any items added after that. I have done a little searching and have found that after loading the TableVIew for the first time, the fetchResults is only seeing however many entities it saw the first time it loaded. For example, if I started the app, added 5 photos with text, then ran the TableViewController, I would see 5 items correctly displayed. I could go back to the main page and then add another photo with text, but if I went back to the TableVIewController I would only see the 5 photos I added before opening the TableViewController.

In the class for the TableViewController I have set the  and am using all of it's normal methods inside my TableViewController.m file.

Totally clueless. Help!

**EDIT: Here is some of my code**

**From: ViewController.m that will save data**

```
    - (IBAction)saveTarget:(id)sender {
    //Only save if there is an image other than the stock photo
    if (self.image != [UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo-Video-Slr-camera-icon"]) {

        //Grab the main ManagedObjectContext from the AppDelegate
        sTCAppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context =[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        //Get the Target model from CoreData
        [self setTarget:[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TargetData" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

        //Set the properties of the TargetData model
        self.target.weaponData = self.weaponData.text;
        self.target.bulletType = self.bulletType.text;
        self.target.stanceType = self.stanceType.text;
        self.target.distanceData = self.distanceData.text;
        self.target.targetNotes = self.targetNotes.text;
        self.target.sightType = self.sightType.text;
        self.target.scoreData = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.scoreData.text intValue]];

        //Set image to smaller size for storage
        UIImage *image = [self resizeImage:self.image toWidth:50 andHeight:50];
        //Save as PNG NSData for compression
        self.target.targetImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        //Set a date property to use for organizing by most recently saved
        self.target.timeStamp = [NSDate date];

        //Save to context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ( ![context save:&error] ){
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        //Jump back to main page
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        //set images back to nil for next time AddTarget is opened
        image = nil;
        self.image = nil;
        NSLog(@"Data Saved");
    }
    //Return alert if user has not entered a photo
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"We're Sorry!" message:@"You must enter at least a photo to save target data." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

**From: TableViewController.m that shows data**

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"number of sections:%lu",(unsigned long)[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]);
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"%lu", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"Ran Cell Configure");
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TargetData *target = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:target.targetImage];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", target.scoreData];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = target.weaponData;
}

#pragma mark- FetchedResultsControllerDelegate Methods

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    sTCAppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TargetData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:0];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedRequestsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedRequestsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedRequestsController;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (IBAction)mainMenu:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So yes, I am using the  Methods in the TableViewController implementation.

**EDIT 2**

I usually run my app on my actual iPhone to test it because then I can use the camera in my device. To see what the console might say about my problem, I added some images to the simulator and ran it on the simulator. This time, after adding an photo with text, opening the TableViewController, then adding another photo, I got a huge crash error report after trying to open the TableViewController again.

Here is the terminating part of the error:

2014-01-13 13:09:38.759 Target Tracker[25124:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CoreData: FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptor without either disabling caching or using +deleteCacheWithName:'

Any clue what that means?

**RESOLVED**

The problem was that I was caching the FetchResults when I ran the TableViewController. When I added another entity to the model and tried to return a new fetchResult, it didn't match the cached version which returned a critical CoreData error. I didn't see it as an error because I was not originally running the app in a simulator, but instead on my actual device. Once I ran it in the simulator I was able to see this error.

In short- I needed to set my "cacheName" to nil when I initialized the NSFetchedResultsController

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedRequestsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

For more information see this post: [NSFetchedResultsController crashing on performFetch: when using a cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709768/nsfetchedresultscontroller-crashing-on-performfetch-when-using-a-cache)

Comment: are you sure that you are saving the context after adding objects to it?

Comment: Does it work if you set  `cacheName:nil` when creating the fetched results controller?

Comment: Try this line just before the NSFetchedResultsController alloc:

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:[@"Master"];

Comment: Re: Edit 2.  I suspect the last time you ran it on the simulator you had a different predicate.  If this is not happening on a re-run of the current code base I would not worry about it.

Comment: Yep. cacheName:nil fixes everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was caching the FetchResults when I ran the TableViewController. When I added another entity to the model and tried to return a new fetchResult, it didn't match the cached version which returned a critical CoreData error. I didn't see it as an error because I was not originally running the app in a simulator, but instead on my actual device. Once I ran it in the simulator I was able to see this error.

In short- I needed to set my "cacheName" to nil when I initialized the NSFetchedResultsController

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedRequestsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

For more information see this post: [NSFetchedResultsController crashing on performFetch: when using a cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709768/nsfetchedresultscontroller-crashing-on-performfetch-when-using-a-cache)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you are saving the context after adding objects to it?
After inserting objects, call

```
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error;
```

Comment: That is only true if the changes are made on a different context.  If you update the current context the changes will fire immediately.  A save may not necessarily be required.

Answer (score 0):

The NSFetchedResultsController will not update until it receive a save context notification. This is usually performed when you call the method:

```
[yourManagedObjectContext save:&error]
```

when the fetched results controller receive the update, some calls are performed to its delegate, see the docs for something called NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and implement all of it's methods to update your tableview. That was the right way, you can also implement only one method to see if this works:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: That is only true if the changes are made on a different context.  If you update the current context the changes will fire immediately.  A save may not necessarily be required.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not implementing the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods.  Perhaps show some of the code for your `UITableViewController`?

### Update

Ok, your code looks good; really good.

So the obvious, easy possibilities are out.  Next step is to put some break points (or logs) into the `-saveTarget:`, `-fetchedResultsController` and the delegate methods and make sure everything is firing.

With the code you provided you should be seeing updates.  Which hints at something not being fired.

Comment: I added my save code and most of my code from my UITableVIewController.

Comment: I added an error report from when I tried to run it on the simulator. Any clue what that is talking about?